# Can't convert label text to int (number in label is fetched from MySQL)

Tags: c#

Label is set from MySQL in code and i put transforming the value to int on button

```
var x = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Balance.Text);

        label4.Text = x.ToString(); //temp
```

I keep getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Here is code for which puts value in lbl_Balance (label)

```
 MySqlConnection myconnbalance = new MySqlConnection(balanceConn);
            string sqlbalance = "SELECT Balance FROM user_data_new WHERE Username='" + loggeduser + "'"; // string sqlbalance = "SELECT 'Balance' FROM 'user_data_new' WHERE 'Username'='" + loggeduser + "'"; 
            MySqlDataAdapter dabalance = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlbalance, myconnbalance);
            DataTable dtbalance = new DataTable();
            dabalance.Fill(dtbalance);
            if (dtbalance.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Doesn't exists");
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                lbl_Balance.Visible = true;
                lbl_Balance.Text = "Balance: "+dtbalance.Rows[0][0].ToString(); //not working?! 


            }
            myconnbalance.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        {
        }
```

Comment: What IS the value of x?

Comment: What is the value you are trying to convert? That exception means it's not a valid number.

Comment: x is newly created value to store int and yes i know what that exception means just couldn't find solution how to fix this. To be in context it's user balance value which i got from MySQL i need this to be int so i can substract from it and update to db once user will place bet

Comment: Why are you storing an int as a string in your database?

Comment: In your response you did everything except answer the question: What is the value you are trying to convert? What is `lbl_Balance.Text`?

Comment: lbl_Balance.Text is label which is displaying value which i got from mysql it's stored as int in db

Comment: Then use the value you retrieve from the database? I don't fully understand your problem, honestly.

Comment: That's still not a *value*. I'm looking for the *value* that you're trying to convert to an int. However your code provided enough: Your label is going to end up holding the value "Balance: ####". The "Balance: " portion is not convertable to int, thus your exception. You need to move the "Balance: " part of the string to another label, or strip it off before you convert.

Comment: Glorin Oakenfoot just found out and thanks so much for answer!

Comment: As an aside, you should be storing this value as a field or property within your form and not relying on the label to hold state for you. The label should reflect the state of the balance, but should not be relied upon to hold that state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Balance.Text.Trim());
```

Try trim if there is any white space in text.

Comment: He is getting his value from MySql database and the datatype was already int in his database.

Comment: int should not get that error thats why I am thinking of some additional white space being at some stage of fetching and assigning the value to label.

Comment: you should remove the text "Balance:" from the text with substring and then do the trim.

Comment: @Gautam whitespace does not matter.

Comment: White and text "Balance:" other than number has been added manually in the text, Thats why I suggested on getting rid of those before converting to int. I am just trying to help him here.